# Non-youtube, vimeo product video

Tags: product, magento-2.1, video

Is it possible to upload product videos to Magento2.1.x that are hosted on own private server?
We're open to any solution possible.
Thanks.

Comment: I've been using https://github.com/videojs I don't have a full write up on how I implement it but here is a quick overview. Update the product page to look for a product attribute. Explode attribute at , to get array of videos to push into the player. It handles both local and youtube videos if you add-on https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube